# Create new process in separate function [c]

Tags: c, process

I wanna create spare process (child?) in specific function called eg. void process(). I want just to create that child process and do nothing with it. I just wanna it alive and do nothing while main() of my app will be working as I want. 
In some point of my app's main() I will be killing child process and then respawn it again. Any ideas how to do that ?

I have something like that but when I'm using this function to create process I get everything twice. Its like after initiation of process() every statement is done twice and i dont want it. After adding sleep(100) after getpid() in child section seems working fine but I cannot kill it.

```
int process(int case){

   if(case==1){
            status=1;
            childpid = fork();      
            if (childpid >= 0) /* fork succeeded */
            {
                if (childpid == 0) /* fork() returns 0 to the child process */
                {
                    printf("CHILD  PID: %d\n", getpid());
                }
        /* fork() returns new pid to the parent process *//*        else 
                {
                }*/
            }
            else
            {
                perror("fork"); 
                exit(0); 
            }
    }  
    else{
        if(status!=0){
            status=0;
            //kill!!!!

            system(a); //getting kill -9 PID ; but PID is equal 0 here...
            printf("\nkilling child");
        }
    }           
    }
```

how to just spawn new child process and let it just exist, like some sort of worker in C#?

Comment: You will need [signals](http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/all-about-linux-signals?page=10).

Comment: @iharob - will singal create new process?

Comment: no, it will help you kill the process when you want to. The process will be created with `fork()`.

Comment: ok, but why PID is equal 0 when i do printf in child section and is equal 0 when i trying ot get it from main() section

Comment: `fork()` will return `0` in the child process and the pid of the child in the parent process, so once you have a non-zero pid that would be your child and you can kill it with `kill(pid, signal)` where the signal could have a handler in the child process that you can use for example, to do cleanup before dying.

Comment: i totally dont understand why i cannot just create spare process in spare function which wont destroy rest of done code or wont execute it twice... I just wanna create it in function, forget about it and kill when i want to... C# destroyed my programming view...

Comment: You may find posix_spawn more convenient. Fork is actually cloning the process in a funny way; once the call succeeds, *both* processes will return from fork call; they will see different return values so it is possible to determine if a process is the parent or the child.

Comment: thanks Nick! Thats exacly what I wanted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are in Linux, here's an example that might clarify your view: parent process spawns a child, the child calls `pause()` which suspends it until a signal is delivered, and finally parent process `kill`'s the child with SIGKILL.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0) { perror("fork"); exit(0); }

    if (pid == 0) {
       printf("Child process created and will now wait for signal...\n");
       pause(); //waits for signal
    }
    else {
       //do some other work in parent process here
       printf("Killing child (%ld) from parent process!", (long) pid);
       kill(pid, SIGKILL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please note that `fork()` returns:

- `<0` on failure
- `0` in child process
- the child's pid in parent process.